# Does clicking "Not interested" prevent an employer from making any future communication with me?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Some employer contacted me with an offer, and I clicked "Not Interested", since I didn't want to change my job right now.

After that I sent the employer a general question about the company, and haven't received an answer yet.

Since afaik the messages an employer can send are limited, is it possible at all for the employer to send me a message, after I clicked "Not Interested"?

Comment: A slight rewording of the title might be in order; I thought this question was about an employer pestering you despite your declining their offer.

Comment: @Antti29 edited, but there maybe something better to do

Comment: I've just edited the title, hopefully it's a little clearer as I also thought this was about some kind of harassment

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've done same thing, got offer, clicked not interested and then responded with reasons why I don't want to change my current position.

Few hours later I've got response from the guy where he said 'thank your for replying etc...'

Here is print screen. It is somewhat safe to assume that being interested shares maybe your email address or phone number from profile and/or might be quick way to show that you are interested and saying not interested is just quick way to respond negatively and/or not share details.

Look at upper right corner, there is specific button to block somebody.

[image]

Comment: Oh, wow. I find this pretty surprising.  I thought the purpose of the messaging interface was to prevent sharing of contact information -- especially for a "not interested."

Comment: While I haven't used it personally, I'd be shocked if they gave out personal info. Did you get an email from the employer _directly_, or was it sent through Stack Overflow?

Comment: This is stack overflow message inbox. They don't give out your info, but it would be kinda logical if I say that I am interested that they will share my full CV that I have on stack overflow and maybe some personal info like email address. However as stated before, I don't know if they give out email and phone in any case (SO has my email, but not my phone number anyways)